# All widgets disappear once I try to create image with canvas

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from os import close
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def selectname():
    
    mainmenu = Tk()
    mainmenu.title("PROF NAME")
    mainmenu.geometry("1200x600")

    lobby = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("CAU_310_MAP/Pictures/lobby.png"))
    
    canvas = Canvas(mainmenu, width = 1200, height = 600)
    canvas.pack(fill='both', expand = True)
    
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=lobby,anchor = "nw")
    canvas.create_text(600, 75, text = '편의시설을 선택해주세요', font='Arial 30')
    
    btnCAUburger=Button(mainmenu, padx=3, pady=3, text="카우버거", font="Arial 30 bold")
    btnTouslesjours=Button(mainmenu, padx=3, pady=3, text="뚜레쥬르", font="Arial 30 bold")
    btnMorningGlory=Button(mainmenu, padx=3, pady=3, text="모닝글로리", font="Arial 30 bold")
    btnPostOffice=Button(mainmenu, padx=3, pady=3, text="우체국", font="Arial 30 bold")
    btnHairNu=Button(mainmenu, padx=3, pady=3, text="헤어누", font="Arial 30 bold")
    btnSevenEleven=Button(mainmenu, padx=3, pady=3, text="세븐일레븐", font="Arial 30 bold")
    btnCanon=Button(mainmenu, padx=3, pady=3, text="캐논", font="Arial 30 bold")
    btn310Ricenoodle=Button(mainmenu, padx=3, pady=3, text="310쌀국수", font="Arial 30 bold")

    btnCAUburger.place(x=150, y=180)
    btnTouslesjours.place(x=370, y=180)
    btnMorningGlory.place(x=590, y=180)
    btnPostOffice.place(x=850, y=180)
    btnHairNu.place(x=160, y=360)
    btnSevenEleven.place(x=350, y=360)
    btnCanon.place(x=620, y=360)
    btn310Ricenoodle.place(x=780, y=360)

mainmenu = Tk()
mainmenu.title("CAU 310 GUIDE MAP")
mainmenu.geometry("1200x600")

lobby = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("CAU_310_MAP/Pictures/lobby.png"))

canvas = Canvas(mainmenu, width = 1200, height = 600)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand = True)

canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=lobby,anchor = "nw")
canvas.create_text(600, 50, text = '310관에 오신 걸 환영합니다', font='Arial 30')

btnconvenience = Button(mainmenu, padx=5, pady=5, text="편의시설", font="times 20", command=selectname)

btnconvenience.place(x=460, y=450)


mainmenu.mainloop()
```

I was working with this code above and ran into a problem with the canvas. I checked that the background image is successfully created by `canvas.create_image` but when I press `btnconvenience`, and opens the next window, the all the buttons and widgets I made are gone. Also what I've checked so far is that once I turn line16: `canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=lobby,anchor = "nw")` and choose not to create background image, the buttons and widgets that disappeared comes back. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here please?

Comment: Add `global lobby` to the start of `selectname`. Also add `master=mainmenu` to the `ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)`. That will fix 2 common mistakes that you made. Not sure if it will help with the actual question.

Comment: first of why are you even using `.place`? second don't use another `Tk` instance, use `Toplevel` instead